# shell script for finding recently accessed file in linux

Tags: linux

print the name of the most recently accessed file in the directory `/var/run/log/` whose name is of the form `access-<DDD>.log` (here `<DDD>` represents exactly 3 digits; thus the filename consists of `access-` followed by exactly 3 digits, followed by `.log`

Comment: What is your issue with this assignment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're demanding we do your assignment for you without any visible attempt by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls -tu | grep -e '^access-[0-9]\{3\}\.log$' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Fixed again.  I think that should do it.  <:)

Comment: @Kusalananda Now `awk` seems unnecessary (without the `-l` option to `ls`).

Comment: The `^` anchor would make the expression _never_ match with `ls -l` as you have more data on the line before the filename. If you _really_ want to use `ls -l`, then swap places on `awk` and `grep`, or use `awk '$NF ~ /^expression$/ { print $NF }'` to combine them. With `ls -l` and `print $NF` in `awk`, you lose the ability handle filenames with spaces though. Consider doing some testing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
print /var/run/log/access-[[:digit:]](#c3).log(.oa[1])
```

Here, `[[:digit:]](#c3)` will match exactly three digit characters. After that, the string `.log` must occur in the name. The dot in `(.oa[1])` qualifies the globbing pattern so that only regular files are matched and the `oa` sorts them in decreasing `atime` order. The `[1]` returns only the first matching name (the most recently accessed one). The `print` utility will print the resulting pathname.

Change `print` to `basename` to only output the filename, without the path.

---

If this is a homework assignment and you're supposed to write a `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

zsh -o extended_glob -c 'print /var/run/log/access-[[:digit:]](#c3).log(.oa[1])'
```